# Getting a list of items from document library using PowerShell in SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

So if I have the URL for a Document Library, how can I get all the items (in this case, folders) from inside the library? I've tried a few different things, but I can't seem to get it.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb($completeUrl)
$spDocumentLibrary = $completeUrl + "/DocumentLibrary"
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity http://url.com
$website = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$listItem = $website.GetListItem($completeUrl)
```

And it fails with an `Exception calling "GetListItem" with "1" argument(s)...`

I'm not reeaally sure where to go from here. What I'm interested in is getting all the folders I have in the document library, which I know is found at `$completeUrl + /DocumentLibrary` which would equal something like `http://url.com/../../DocumentLibrary` for example. But I'm apparently going at it wrong.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know your SharePoint library construction, however, from my point of view, you are missing list selection.

```
$spDocumentLibrary = $completeUrl + "/DocumentLibrary"
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity http://url.com
$website = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$list = $website.Lists["List_Name_Here"]
$items = $list.GetItems()
```

Answer (score 3):

This will print out all folder names of a document library:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
$web = Get-SPWeb 'http://urltoyourweb'
$list = $web.Lists['DocumentLibrary']

function ListFolders($folder) {
    Write-Host $folder.Name
    $folder.Subfolders | % { if( $_.item -ne $null) { ListFolders $_}}
}

ListFolders $list.RootFolder
```

Explanation:

ListFolders is a function, that calls itself, if a subfolder is not null. This is called a recursive function. Now, we supply it with the root folder of a SPList and then iterate over its subfolders collection (`%` is short for `For-Each`)

If this is too much inline piping for your taste, you could always write the more readable version of it:

```
##Same as $folder.Subfolders | % { if( $_.item -ne $null) { ListFolders $_}}
foreach($sfolder in $folder.SubFolders)
{
    if ($sfolder.item -ne $null)
    {
        ListFolders $sfolder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I had to do was call $items at the end to get the results. I initially thought the `$list.GetItems()` was going to return the list of items.

So my script looks like this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$spDocumentLibrary = $completeUrl + "/DocumentLibrary"
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity https://url.com
$website = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$list = $website.Lists["List_Name_Here"]
$items = $list.GetItems()
$items | select -property Title,DisplayName,Url | `
Export-CSV -Path "\\DesiredLocation\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

As you can see I piped my results to a CSV file. Just wanted to note the following things.

1. For this to work for you change the generic https://url.com to the legit URL that you are trying to get the results from.
2. Change the Export-CSV -Path "DesiredLocation" to an actual file path (i.e. c:\users\yourprofile\desktop\filename.csv
3. Change the CSV FileName to something that makes sense to you.